# How to input value in code mirror using selenium web driver?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm currently facing an issue related to input values in code mirror (FYI: input is html code)

Any help much appreciated!!

This is what i was doing so far (but i need to insert values in each line of code mirror)

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
Js.executeScript("arguments[0].CodeMirror.setValue(\"" + value + "\");", driver.findElementBy(By.id("id")));
```

[image]

Page source code is:

```
<div class="CodeMirror cm-s-default">
<div style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 3px; height: 0px; top: 5px; left: 35px;">
<textarea wrap="off" style="position: absolute; padding: 0px; width: 1px; height: 1em; outline: medium none;" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="CodeMirror-vscrollbar" cm-not-content="true" style="min-width: 18px;">
<div style="min-width: 1px; height: 0px;"></div>
</div>
<div class="CodeMirror-hscrollbar" cm-not-content="true" style="min-height: 18px;">
<div style="height: 100%; min-height: 1px; width: 0px;"></div>
</div>
<div class="CodeMirror-scrollbar-filler" cm-not-content="true"></div>
<div class="CodeMirror-gutter-filler" cm-not-content="true"></div>
<div class="CodeMirror-scroll" tabindex="-1" draggable="true">
<div class="CodeMirror-sizer" style="margin-left: 30px; margin-bottom: 0px; border-right-width: 30px; min-height: 31px; min-width: 7px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
<div style="position: relative; top: 0px;">
<div class="CodeMirror-lines">
<div style="position: relative; outline: medium none;">
<div class="CodeMirror-measure">
<span>
<span>​</span>
x
</span>
</div>
<div class="CodeMirror-measure"></div>
<div style="position: relative; z-index: 1;"></div>
<div class="CodeMirror-cursors">
<div class="CodeMirror-cursor" style="left: 4px; top: 0px; height: 22.85px;"> </div>
</div>
<div class="CodeMirror-code">
<div style="position: relative;">
<div class="CodeMirror-gutter-wrapper" style="left: -30px;">
<div class="CodeMirror-linenumber CodeMirror-gutter-elt" style="left: 0px; width: 21px;">1</div>
</div>
<pre class=" CodeMirror-line ">
<span>
<span cm-text="">​</span>
</span>
</pre>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

So the problem is how to input value in different lines in code mirror..

Comment: 'input values are html code' - dont you think write this html Would be bad idea?

Comment: @kotoj yeah it's a bad idea, but we've requirement to do so.. i'm trying to input html to code mirror it's just adding it in one line..

Comment: I mean you should attach this html to your question...

Comment: updated my question..

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: Updated my question with screen shot..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to input code mirror with line breaks, by changing the input value to this..

`<html>\\r<test>\\r</html>`

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear but I think what you are looking for is to insert text into different lines instead of all on one line. If that's the case, you need to insert `\n` in your string where you want carriage returns.

An example string would be `string sample = "<html>\n  <test>\n</html>"` which should produce

```
<html>
  <test>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't see your code so I can't help you. Have you googled "unterminated string literal" and found common causes and examined your code for any of those causes?

Comment: was using jsexecutor to input value in code mirror.. following exactly same code

Comment: I'm able to input values in code mirror with line breaks using `\\r`.. Thanks @JeffC for your time